# Check for Blank variables of Object

Tags: java, string

I have a pojo class

```
class Foo{
 String a
 String b
 .
 .
 // nearly 250 data members
 // all have getters and setter

}
```

Now when i create object of class 
how can i check that any data member in object is blank

i am using following approach

```
public  boolean clearBlank()
{

    if(StringUtils.isBlank(this.getA()))
        return true;
    if(StringUtils.isBlank(this.getB()))
        return true;
    if(StringUtils.isBlank(this.getC()))
        return true;
    .
    .
    .
    // similarly for all 250 data member
    return false;

}
```

IS there any better approach intead of checking by calling all 250 getters of object?

Comment: 250 fields is a disaster. You should split your class up.

Comment: If you're using them all for the same meaning -- then why not use an array?

Comment: This could be a very legitimate sort of class for a Java class that represents a large data object, I have seen lots of these. I think this requirement is a fair one.

Comment: @FrancisUpton - if you've seen a lot of classes like this, you've probably got serious code quality concerns in your workplace.

Comment: @StephenC, well they are not classes in my workspace, they are customer classes. And to be fair, they are not 250 fields, but maybe 50. Consider the Java representation of very large XML standards like GS1, FpML or ACORD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use Java Reflection to go through all of the fields of the object and get their values to do the comparison.

Like this:

```java
public static boolean hasBlankVariables(Object obj) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (!field.isAccessible()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
        }
        // Danger!
        String str = (String) field.get(obj);
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(str)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please help on how to implement

Comment: @Abhishekj: Given that Francis has given you a broad direction, how much research have you done in that direction? What have you tried, and where are the problems?

Comment: You can easily Google "Java Reflection" and find pointers to the API and many examples. It's only a few lines of code.